# Jenkins - Trigger Job after certain time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to see if there is a plugin that can do what I want or something I am missing with regards to Jenkins triggers. To give you an example of what we want to do let me explain how things are happening currently.

1. A merge is made
2. Jenkins picks up on merge, pulling changes on remote build machine
3. Server is stopped
4. Build, checks, etc are done
5. Server is started

So the above is all well and good and working, however what we want to do is trigger the server stop and build after the merge is picked-up by Jenkins. Here is the catch though, it is a large project, with multiple tracks and we could have say 4-10 merges done within a 10-30 minute window. So obviously we do not want to have 4-10 jobs in the queue all running the same thing.

So what would be the best approach to achieving the above, i.e. Jenkins triggers based on merge, say waits for x minutes, if no other merges, then triggers the build process, if new merge reset counter back to x minutes and wait again?

Are there any plugins or triggers built into Jenkins that we can achieve this with? (I couldn't find anything obvious) Or is this a case we need to parameterise the build and have some script running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not aware of any plugin which does this. But if you're using the job type Pipeline or willing to convert it to Pipelines, then the following Jenkins pipeline will do the trick:

```
// Sleep for a certain time, in this case 20 seconds
sleep(20);

// Check if there is a newer build, if there is abort this one.
if (currentBuild.nextBuild != null) {
  echo "Got newer build, aborting this one!"
  currentBuild.result = Result.NOT_BUILT;
  return;
}

// Do the rest of building here
```

Comment: Sorry for delay on accepting, had to play around with pipelines, but I managed to get what I wanted use them. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score -1):

You can run the below command from URL and it serves the purpose.
https:///build?delay=600sec

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).